# The best way to organise data on SD card for fast searching

Tags: java, android, algorithm, search, hash

I have the next model, that I need to store on SD card:

```
Artist->Album->Track

Playlist (user adds here tracks)
```

Currently I store tracks on one level using
`playlistid_artistid_albumid_trackid` name. But after downloading a lot of tracks performance falls. What is the best way to store my hierarchical data(**playlists actually are not in the hierarchy** - that is a problem) for fast searching?

**EDIT:**

I need to have possibility for looking for:

- tracks by trackId, albumId, artistId, playlistId
- albums by artistId, playlistId
- artists by playlistId

  and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reorganised my structure to the next one:

```
 - Tree structure "Artist->Album->Track"` on the SD card
 - DB on the SD card that links Playlists and Tracks ids.
```

It resolved my performance problem.